# Problems visualizing raw text in QPlainText widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I'm trying to make a base64 coder/decoder and visualize results in Qt (4.7.3) in Ubuntu.

I'm using both `QPlainText` to paste code and to present results. I have no problem decoding, because the result is correct, but when I try to encrypt, the results are Chinese character and non readable chars.

I think that my error is with the encoding of the widget or with the `QString`, because the codification algorithm is correct.

Some ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe the problem is in your encrypt function.

Comment: No, the encrypt function has been tested and in producion for a long time.

Comment: Can you expand on the problem please?  If you just take some data, encode it and display it, the result is unicode characters in the QPlainTextEdit widget?  Can you show the code where you set the text in the widget?

Answer (score 0):

If encoding works in 8 bit, it may produce, by chance, UTF-8 sequences of characters that represent chinese characters (or from other languages, for the matter). This also depends on the default `QString` encoding you selected, etc., but with base64 it will work for any encoding. For the encoded string, try to base64 it before showing it into the widget.

Comment: How could I select the encoding in a QString?

Comment: You can look at the documentation of QTextCodec: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcodec.html